# Google Drive Uploads (CWE Fixes)

Tags: google-drive-api, owasp, penetration-testing

So I'm trying to get permission from google so that they allow my users to upload profile pictures by directly connecting to their google drive account. After a lot of back and forth emailing google asked to run some security scans against my application and fix any CWEs that might show up and get my report validated.

[email from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiOjH.png)

Now I took the open source tools approach and ran a scan using ZAP OWASP. I have quite a few Alerts in there with CWE IDs. Alert levels include high, medium, low, and informational.
Has anyone gone through getting this validation from google? Do I need to fix all of the alerts including the informational level CWE IDs before submitting my report for validation?